# Spring security adfs authentication

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs, spring-saml

I'm quite new to spring and security. I secure my app using basic spring security configuration.
here is my security.xml:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                    default-target-url="/#"
                    always-use-default-target="true"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login"
        />
        <http-basic />
        <logout />
    </http>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

It works great, but now I need to use adfs authentication for my app(running on localhost:8888)

I have ADFS server running on localhost:8080, and on the page http://localhost:8080/adfs/ls I see:
[auth page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du1ER.jpg)

Now I need to authenticate user using adfs server.
I think I should send saml request(or smth like that) to the given adfs server, but have no idea how to do that.

So, how do I achieve authenticatoin using this adfs server?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What version of AD FS are you using? What OS is this running on? If you are using Windows Server 2008 R2 and earlier OS, then the AD FS provided as is doesn't support SAML2. That logon screen doesn't look like an AD FS that supports SAML2.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html